# Can kafka be used to obtain GoogleAnalytics data and processed through spark streaming?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

Can you please anyone tried to integrate google analytics with kafka ..And the processed those data in spark streaming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A little late since this question was asked but...

I created a python application that demonstrates how to pull information from Google Analytics and push those metrics to a Kafka topic.  Soon I should have code that demonstrates analyzing that data.

https://github.com/admintome/analytics-intake

Hopefully, that will demonstrate how to accomplish what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

There is no API available for scala to access the google analytic.